# Not able to map any keys between F1 to F5 in gvim

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc

I am not able to map any keys between F1 to F5 in gvim through vimrc. However all the keys after F5 are being properly mapped.

Here is my vimrc file content.

```
map <F1> :q!<ESC>
map <F4> :E<ESC>
map <F3> :sp<ESC>
map <F6> :vsp<ESC>
map <F7> :tabe %<ESC>:set syntax=systemverilog<ESC>:E<ESC>
```

F6 & F7 are properly mapped, when I open my gvim, but F1, F3 & F4 are not mapped.

Interestingly, if I manually do mapping through map command, after opening the gvim, then I am able to map even all those 3 keys as well.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: There could be a plugin that remaps keys after vimrc processing. Try to start vim and check what mapping is on the key after start `:map <F1>`

Comment: Yes. I checked that through `nmap` and it is showing `<F1> <F1>` only.

Comment: If there is no mapping vim shows `No mapping found` so there is a mapping F1 to F1 in your case. Check who did that mapping `:verbose nmap <F4>`

Comment: Yes Thanks for that. I have checked it. My `vimrc` data was being overwritten by `gvimrc` file. So I have renamed my `vimrc` to `gvimrc` and it is working now. 1. Is it proper solution? 2. Now after renaming the `:E` command is not working in gvim.

Comment: Hi, the :E issue is also resolved, when I keep both .vimrc & .gvimrc file in the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Key mapping in `.vimrc` can be  overwritten by other initialization files. It is possible to check what mapping is bound to the `F1` key for example:

```
:map <F1>
```

If there is something else than in the `.vimrc` then the mapping is replaced or removed. Verbose option shows where the key mapping comes from:

```
:verbose map <F1>
...
Last set from ...
```

The mapping was overwritten from `.gvimrc` in this case. Vim process `.vimrc` first and then `.gvimrc` so key mapping in the `.gvimrc` always win. `.gvimrc` should contain configuration specific for graphic environment as menu extensions, color schemes, special mouse settings and all other configuration options that are irrelevant for terminal mode.

Solution for this case is to remove key mappings from `.gvimrc` so it does not overwrite mapping from `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but I think I know why the problem occurs. I also have the same problem now and I think it's because if you're using a laptop, f1-f6 are mapped to mute, volume down, volume up, pause/play, and forward respectively.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1142717)